# How to get instance created by <jsp:useBean scope="session"> in a servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, usebean

I have a JSP with the following `<jsp:useBean>`:

```
<jsp:useBean id="res" class="mycompany.Resource" scope="session" />
```

I would like to get the instance from the session in a servlet. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is very cryptic, but to start with, are you familiar with how this `<jsp:useBean>` works under the covers? `session.setAttribute()`, `session.getAttribute()` and so on?

Comment: Thanks, that comment was really helpful. I was able to get the object from session.getAttribute("res") in User class.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the bad title/question and posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stored as a session attribute under the key as specified by `<jsp:useBean id>`. You can get it by [`HttpSession#getAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) passing the key as follows:

```
Resource resource = (Resource) request.getSession().getAttribute("res");
// ...
```